# Live capture via V4L2 using external trigger freezes on DQBUF

Tags: raspberry-pi, camera, buffer, video-capture, v4l2

I'm trying to set up a live capture of frames from a USB camera on a Raspberry. I have decided to use Video4Linux to grab the frames. I'm also using an external trigger which I decided to use because of image processing - I need to capture a frame, process it and just then capture a new one - therefor I request and allocate just a single buffer. I control the external trigger by one of RPi's GPIO pins. My capturing loop goes :

1. ioctl call to queue a buffer
2. external trigger realized by GPIO
3. ioctl call to dequeue a buffer

The program acts inconsistently - sometimes it freezes, sometimes it doesn't. Every time it freezes, it gets stuck on the ioctl call to dequeue a buffer. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong? Here is the code of the loop:

```
while( frames != 50 ) {
    // Queue the buffer
    if(ioctl(fd, VIDIOC_QBUF, &bufferinfo) < 0){
        perror("VIDIOC_QBUF");
        exit(1);
    }

    // external trigger realized by rising edge signal
    digitalWrite(0, HIGH);
    delay(50);
    digitalWrite(0, LOW);
    delay(50);
    
    // Dequeue the buffer
    if( ioctl(fd, VIDIOC_DQBUF, &bufferinfo) < 0) {
        perror("VIDIOC_DQBUF");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```